# How to run in background an .exe program withArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.2, python-2.7

I am working with the ArcGIS program that reads Python language. For that I've already implement scripts as script tool on the ArcGIS.
Now I need to run in background an exe program "gams".
Is it possible to do directly from the ArcGIS? Or is it possible to do with a new python script? And how can I do this?

Comment: You have error messages in a comment on an answer to your question but what we need is a code snippet that you are running and any errors that it produces in your question.

Answer (score 6):

You can try to use a python script and use one of the two following modules. But think of it carefully as running a program out of a script can do many unpleasent things.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['C:\\folder\\gams.exe'])

import os
os.system('"C:\\folder\\gams.exe"')
```

Update as it is about a file of the type .gms:

Check out the answers on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811691/running-an-outside-program-executable-in-python

Comment: Thank's! I run a .gms file and I did:
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['F:\Otim\correct\ElectGV03.gms'])
but arcgis gives me an error:
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 70, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\subprocess.py", line 493, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\Lib\subprocess.py", line 896, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Comment: Ok thats different. I thought your programm is gams.exe and not xxx.gms . You have the problem that your windows does not recognize the filetype. Is the needed software installed? Can you double-click the file and it runs? Otherwise you have to assign the file type to the programm that should run it.

Comment: Yes, Gams is installed at my computer. When I open the gams program and run the file .gms it runs, yes...

Comment: See update on the answer. There are different possiblities and one should work for you....

Comment: I put a link in the original answer where there are different options discussed to open a program via python.

Comment: I tryed to do this but gives me an error...